# How to change and save variable in different files

Tags: python

I have three python files:

**a.py**

```py
theVariable = "Hello!"
```

**b.py**

```py
import a
a.theVariable = "Change"
```

**c.py**

```py
import a

while True:
    print(a.theVariable)
```

I want c.py to print out "Change" instead of "Hello!". How can I do this and why wont this work?
There needs to be separate files because b.py would be running a Tkinter gui.

Comment: `c` cannot print out "change" without importing and running the code in `b`, but even then, you're importing `a` twice, and not sharing the state of that variable

Comment: If you're running a GUI, please actually show your GUI code as a [mcve] via an [edit] otherwise, the answers you get are not relevant and guesses, at best

Comment: What is the reason for trying to do this? I ask because mutating global variables like you want is a source of difficult-to-find bugs.

Comment: btw, you don't need sockets or any network stack for this...

Answer (score 3):

You can use classes to get an instance variable which holds some state

a.py

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.greeting = "Hello"
```

And create functions so that you can defer actions on references

b.py

```
def changer(f):
    f.greeting = "Change"
```

When you import a class and then pass it to a function, you are passing a reference to something that can change state

c.py

```
from a import Foo
from b import changer

a = Foo()
for x in range(10):  # simple example
    if x > 5:
        changer(a)
    print(a.greeting)
```

Comment: It doesn't work because I need at least two separate python files because a.py would be running a tkinter GUI and you can't use a while loop in it because it would stop the other code from working so i need a separate file(b.py) with a while loop detecting change in the variable

Comment: I'm not using a while loop... And you shouldn't "pull" endlessly for a variable change, anyway, you should **push** with a callback for when the variable **does** change. Otherwise, you're wasting CPU cycles

Comment: Using my example, you can declare an instance variable of a class in the GUI. Your class is defined in one file. Your GUI is declared in another. And you can have a thrid file with functions that act as utility methods on instances of your class... Ultimately, the number of files isn't the problem, its how you pass references between them

Comment: @MattyTranmer It sounds like your original question is missing important details about what you are actually trying to do. Please describe more fully what you are trying to accomplish so that we can point you in the right direction to a better solution. Since you are writing a GUI, you should think about this in terms of what the users sees on the screen and what actions the user takes. Don't worry about variables or .py files for now. Those are implementation details that get in the way if you focus on them too early in the process.

Answer (score 1):

a.py

```
theVariable = "Hello!"

def change(variable):
    theVariable = variable
```

b.py

```
import a

change('change')
```

c.py

```
import a

while True:
    print(theVariable)
```

i've been working with PyQt recently and this worked fine. setting a function in the orgin .py file makes it much simpler.

Comment: It doesn't work because I need at least two separate python files because a.py would be running a tkinter GUI and you can't use a while loop in it because it would stop the other code from working so i need a separate file(b.py) with a while loop detecting change in the variable